# Docker build success but page cannot open in browser?

Tags: php, docker, symfony, dockerfile

I am trying to run symfony using docker. This is my dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM php:7.2-cli

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

# install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && composer --ansi --version --no-interaction

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && composer --ansi --version --no-interaction
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring


WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --ansi --no-interaction

EXPOSE 8000
CMD php -S localhost:8000 -t public 0.0.0.0:8000
```

After I build and run `$ docker run -it -p 8000:8000 symfony-tutorial` I get following response

```
D:\docker_test\symfony-4-tutorial>docker run -it -p 8000:8000 symfony-tutorial
PHP 7.2.34 Development Server started at Wed Jan 11 16:40:32 2023
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /app/public
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

But on browser, its empty.
This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. There is nothing in source and network tab

[image]

Comment: _"But on browser, its empty."_ Can you clarify? Do you get a 404 or other status code, is there simply no content and a blank page - what does your browsers dev-tool (F12) say in the source and network tab?

Comment: This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. There is nothing in source and network tab @iLuvLogix

Comment: Then you might want to add that quite relevant info to your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web server binds to localhost, which means that it'll only accept connections from inside the container.

You need to change

```
CMD php -S localhost:8000 -t public 0.0.0.0:8000
```

to

```
CMD php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t public 0.0.0.0:8000
```